# How to scrub a dynamic python dictionary of specific keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

This one is just obtuse enough that no typical answer is bubbling to the top.

The nature of the tool I'm working on dictates we use MongoDB to store 'settings' for about 25 different tools.  Each tool has it's own settings schema, so each document is different, but they're all stored in the same collection and edited on the same edit page which is drawn by json schema.

Not knowing the schema of the dictionary, I'm struggling to figure out how to iterate and sanitize the data, specifically removing passwords.

Given the following dictionary, and knowing that other dicts may have different schemas, how could I traverse every single item in the dict and create a copy, identical *except* with any key == "password" removed?

So:

```
{
  "_enabled": true,
  "instances": [
    {
      "isdefault": true,
      "name": "dev",
      "password": "abc123",
      "url": "http://dev.example.com",
      "user": "buffy"
    },
    {
      "isdefault": false,
      "name": "prod",
      "password": "xxxxx",
      "url": "http://prod.example.com",
      "user": "spike"
    },
    {
      "isdefault": false,
      "name": "qa",
      "password": "dasddf",
      "url": "http://prod.example.com",
      "user": "willow"
    }
  ],
  "label": "MyServers"
}
```

Should result in:

```
{
  "_enabled": true,
  "instances": [
    {
      "isdefault": true,
      "name": "dev",
      "url": "http://dev.example.com",
      "user": "buffy"
    },
    {
      "isdefault": false,
      "name": "prod",
      "url": "http://prod.example.com",
      "user": "spike"
    },
    {
      "isdefault": false,
      "name": "qa",
      "url": "http://prod.example.com",
      "user": "willow"
    }
  ],
  "label": "MyServers"
}
```

Comment: where are you stuck? what did you try? looks like you just have to loop over the dicts in instances and delete the password key/value pair...

Comment: Wait a second, is this even a python dictionary? It looks like json or something else...

Comment: yes it looks like json to mee too

Comment: This is confusing because you're talking about dynamic schemas. If the structure is so different for each dict that you never know what you will encounter, you won't be able to develop an algorithm no matter what approach or language we're talking about. I suspect, however, aschmid has the answer: `for subdict in original_dict['instances']: if 'password' in subdict: del subdict['password']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

deepcopy the dict first, then catch all the dictionaries and remove the password keys:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def remove_pass(v):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        if "password" in v:
            del v["password"]
        for ele in v.values():
            remove_pass(ele)
    elif isinstance(v, Iterable) and not isinstance(v, basestring):
        for ele in v:
            remove_pass(ele)


from pprint import pprint as pp
d = deepcopy(d)
for v in d.values():
   remove_pass(v)
```

Input:

```
{'_enabled': 'true',
 'foo': {'isdefault': 'false',
         'name': 'qa',
         'nested': {'password': 'nested'},
         'password': 'dasddf',
         'url': 'http://prod.example.com',
         'user': 'willow'},
 'instances': [{'isdefault': 'true',
                'name': 'dev',
                'password': 'abc123',
                'url': 'http://dev.example.com',
                'user': 'buffy'},
               {'isdefault': 'false',
                'name': 'prod',
                nested': {'more_nesting': {'even_more_nesting': ({'password': 'foobar'},
                                       {'password': 'foob'}),
                                        'password': 'bar'},
                'password': 'xxxxx',
                'url': 'http://prod.example.com',
                'user': 'spike'},
               {'isdefault': 'false',
                'name': 'qa',
                'password': 'dasddf',
                'url': 'http://prod.example.com',
                'user': 'willow'}],
 'label': 'MyServers'}
```

Output:

```
{'_enabled': 'true',
 'foo': {'isdefault': 'false',
         'name': 'qa',
         'nested': {},
         'url': 'http://prod.example.com',
         'user': 'willow'},
 'instances': [{'isdefault': 'true',
                'name': 'dev',
                'url': 'http://dev.example.com',
                'user': 'buffy'},
               {'isdefault': 'false',
                'name': 'prod',
                'nested': {'more_nesting': {'even_more_nesting': ({}, {})}},
                'url': 'http://prod.example.com',
                'user': 'spike'},
               {'isdefault': 'false',
                'name': 'qa',
                'url': 'http://prod.example.com',
                'user': 'willow'}],
 'label': 'MyServers'}
```

Comment: Even easier than seeing if 'password' is in the dict and then deleting that key/value pair  is `d.pop('password', None)`

Comment: @bgporter,  a lookup is 0(1), not really an issue

Comment: Not even thinking execution time, just clarity of code.  Matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: @bgporter, in this instance I am more worried about the getting code that is flexible and working than anything else

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile and demonstrating this working with more nesting.  I modified it slightly to simply set the value of the password field to "" rather than delete it (so the pop wouldn't have worked anyway), but this is exactly what I needed, and so easy I facepalmed.  (Sometimes we tend to overcomplicate things!)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only want to check containers which are lists or dictionaries and remove key value pairs from dictionary entries which have the `key = "password"`

```
#first copy the structure
new_data = copy.deepcopy(data)

#this is a recursive function. 
#Heavily nested structures may fail due to recursion limit
def clean_hierarchy(ele):
    #lists may contain dictionaries, so clean theses entries
    if isinstance(ele,list):
        for val in ele:
            clean_hierarchy(val)
    if isinstance(ele,dict):
        #remove possible password entry
        if "password" in ele:
            ele.pop("password",None)
        #dictionary may contain more dictionaries. Rinse and repeat!
        for val in ele.values():
            clean_hierarchy(val)

clean_hierarchy(new_data)
```

Comment: this is clearer than the accepted answer because it doesnt use Iterable and basestring, I like it

Answer (score 0):

If you knew the structure of each of your data (i.e., at what depth of an array/dictionary to expect the "password" key), this would be simple. You'd simply need to loop through your list items and dictionaries to find the "password" key.

If the structure of each settings dictionary is truly unpredictable, you'll have to hack together a solution. What I've done in cases like this is dump my JSON to a string, use regex to remove/isolate the data I'm interested in and then load the string back to structured JSON.

Something like this:

import json, re

```
raw_data = """{
  "_enabled": true,
  "instances": [
    {
      "isdefault": true,
      "name": "dev",
      "password": "abc123",
      "url": "http://dev.example.com",
      "user": "buffy"
    },
    {
      "isdefault": false,
      "name": "prod",
      "password": "xxxxx",
      "url": "http://prod.example.com",
      "user": "spike"
    },
    {
      "isdefault": false,
      "name": "qa",
      "password": "dasddf",
      "url": "http://prod.example.com",
      "user": "willow"
    }
  ],
  "label": "MyServers"
}"""

# I load and then dump my raw_data just to iron out any inconsistencies 
# in formatting before applying regex. i.e., inconsistent use of " instead of '
structured_data = json.loads(raw_data)
dumped_data = json.dumps(structured_data)

scrubbed = re.sub(r'"password": ".*?",', '', dumped_data)
structured_scrubbed = json.loads(scrubbed)
```

Results in:

```
structured_scrubbed = {'_enabled': True,
 'instances': [{'isdefault': True,
                'name': 'dev',
                'url': 'http://dev.example.com',
                'user': 'buffy'},
               {'isdefault': False,
                'name': 'prod',
                'url': 'http://prod.example.com',
                'user': 'spike'},
               {'isdefault': False,
                'name': 'qa',
                'url': 'http://prod.example.com',
                'user': 'willow'}],
 'label': 'MyServers'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a general function `getPaths` to find the path of a specific key in a nested dictionary. You can use that to go ahead and find all the paths to your "password" key and then change it, or delete it. This works for all formats/schemas of the json string.

```
def getPaths(dictionary, searchKey):
    '''
    generator to get all paths for the key in the nested dictionary

    '''
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if k == searchKey :
            yield []
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            # if the value if dict, go in recursively and yield the path
            for subkey in getPaths(v, searchKey):
                yield [k]+subkey
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            # if value is a list, for each element in the list, go in recursively and yield the path
            for i, item in enumerate(v):
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    for subkey in getPaths(item, searchKey):
                        yield [k]+[i]+subkey


jsonstring = """{
  "_enabled": true,
  "instances": [
    {
      "isdefault": true,
      "name": "dev",
      "password": "abc123",
      "url": "http://dev.example.com",
      "user": "buffy"
    },
    {
      "isdefault": false,
      "name": "prod",
      "password": "xxxxx",
      "url": "http://prod.example.com",
      "user": "spike"
    },
    {
        "instance2": {
                      "isdefault": false,
                      "name": "qa",
                      "password": "dasddf",
                      "url": "http://prod.example.com",
                      "user": "willow"
                      }
    }
  ],
  "label": "MyServers"
}"""
import json
jsonObj = json.loads(jsonstring)


paths = getPaths(jsonObj , "password")
for path in paths:
    print('path:', path)
```

Result:

```
>>> path: ['instances', 0]
>>> path: ['instances', 1]
>>> path: ['instances', 2, 'instance2']
```